# Scala eq issues

Tags: scala

I am having issues with the following code in Scala

```
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.Assert._

class BoxingTest {

    val holder: Holder[Integer] = new Holder[Integer]();

    @Test
    def Holder_Eq_Primitive(){        
        assertEquals(holder, holder eq 1);
    }

    @Test
    def Holder_Eq_Boxed(){        
        assertEquals(holder, holder eq 1.asInstanceOf[Integer]);
    }

}

class Holder[T] {

    def eq(other: T): Holder[_] = this;
}
```

I get the following error in compilation

```
/BoxingTest.scala:12: error: type mismatch;
[INFO]  found   : Int
[INFO]  required: AnyRef
[INFO] Note: primitive types are not implicitly converted to AnyRef.
[INFO] You can safely force boxing by casting x.asInstanceOf[AnyRef].
[INFO]         assertEquals(holder, holder eq 1);
[INFO]                                     ^
[ERROR] one error found
[INFO] -------------------------
```

Why doesn't the implicit conversion from Int to Integer handle the issue?

I could easily fix the code by not using eq, but this just doesn't seem right. IMHO the available implicit conversions should be applied here.

**UPDATE**

I got the issue fixed by using the signature like this

```
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.Assert._

class BoxingTest {

    @Test
    def Holder_Eq_Primitive(){
        val holder: Holder[Int] = new Holder[Int]();
        assertEquals(holder, holder eq 1);
    }

    @Test
    def Holder_Eq_Boxed(){
        val holder: Holder[Integer] = new Holder[Integer]();
        assertEquals(holder, holder eq 1.asInstanceOf[Integer]);
    }

}

class Holder[T] {

    def eq(other: T): Holder[_] = ...;
}
```

Still, it would be good to use the wrapper types instead.

Comment: Do you mean this question in the context of "how do I make my code work", or "I'm wondering about the background motivations for this design decision in Scala"?

Comment: @Andrzej, a bit of both. I updated my question.

Comment: Btw, any reasons why you use Java's `Integer` instead of Scala's `Int`?

Comment: @soc, using Int fixed the issue, still weird behavior. Thanks.

Comment: @Timo: I'm not sure what you are trying to do in the first place, Scala in fact tries very hard to make the distinction between boxed and unboxed value types invisible. As long as you are not testing Java code, you won't need `Integer` ever.

Comment: @soc, the example is a little bit out of context, I am using the code in the context of a Java framework, which doesn't handle primitive types as generic parameters.

Comment: Ah, OK I understand. Viel Erfolg! :-)

Comment: Don't you think it invites confusion to hide the reference-equality `eq` with a method of the same name that doesn't even return a `Boolean`?

Comment: @rex-kerr, maybe, but using alternatives such as === and !== is confusing as well

Comment: Something is very wrong here. The name and the calls imply that the method eq should test for equality, but it simply ignores its argument and returns a reference to the object it is called on.

Comment: @Jona I removed the misleading implementation. My question was about a method signature which doesn't return Boolean. It's a DSL use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried comparing an `Int` value against integer literal and got some interesting note from the compiler. This may shed some light about the causes of this behaviour.

```
scala> val a = 1
scala> a eq 1
<console>:6: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: ?{val eq: ?}
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method int2Integer in object Predef of type (Int)java.lang.Integer
 and method intWrapper in object Predef of type (Int)scala.runtime.RichInt
 are possible conversion functions from Int to ?{val eq: ?}
       a eq 1
       ^
```

Comment: That's an interesting note. I have already given up on using eq, because of all the related trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is about **Type Erasure** in Java. When you compile the class

```
class Holder[T] {

    def eq(other: T): Holder[_] = this;
}
```

The type `T` will be removed. You can make a test:

[image]

On the other hand, the `Int` class is a subtype of `AnyVal`, not `AnyRef`. Therefore, if you try to apply the method `eq` with an argument `1` which is of type `Int`, an runtime error will be emitted.

PS: Though `Int` can be convert to `java.lang.Integer` implicitly , as Vilius Normantas pointed out, it can be convert to RichInt implicitly either.